# IN, GROUP BY and get AVG with JPA

Tags: hibernate

There are two tables Feedback and Services.

```
feedback                        
--------------------
rating | services_id  

  3  |      1                
  4  |      1                
  2  |      2                

Services 
------------------------
id  |    name
 1  |   Travel
 2  |   Hostel
 3  |   Food
```

How I get ordered list of services according to rating?

Comment: Do you want a SQL query or a Hibernate query?

Comment: I need JPA query... I need to Find rating of each service with in the same query.Then get ordered list of services according to rating of service in feedback table

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the link if this one helps

http://kruders.com/hibernate/hibernate-criteria-on-multiple-tables/

Comment: But I need to Find rating of each service with in the same query.Then Only I can order it. Right?